# divide by zero exception

Tags: c++, exception

Can anyone help me about this? The compiler doesn't recognize the exception e but how I should declare it? The application simply should divide two numbers throwing an exception if the second is 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

float divide(float, float) throw(exception);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  float a,b;

  float c=0;
  cin>>a;
  cin>>b;
  try{
    c=divide(a,b);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    cout<<"You cannot do this";
  };
  return 0;
}

float divide(float a, float b) throw(exception)  {
  float c=a/b;
  if(b==0)
    throw  Exception &e;
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Pre-emptive -1 if this turns out to be an `Exception`/`exception` typo.

Comment: That's certainly part of it. However, I would be very surprised to encounter a compiler that accepts `throw exception &e;`.

Comment: Once you've fixed the typo, you need to test before division, not after. Otherwise, the division would cause undefined behaviour: it might crash the program, and the compiler is allowed to assume it wasn't zero and eliminate the test.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you tried to use a class `Exception` but never declared it. So it does not exist.

You could use one of the standard exception types. In fact, it looks like you may be attempting to use the base class `std::exception`: that's a *lower-case* `e`.

I suggest `std::runtime_error` from `<stdexcept>`, instead.